# NSXMLParser exc bad access error - swift OS X

Tags: swift, macos, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser to parse a xml file on my desktop. The NSXMLParser object gives exc bad access error when calling parse method.

This is the code

```
        let xmlURl = NSHomeDirectory()+"/Desktop/questions.xml"
        let myUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:xmlURl)
        let  myparser =  NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: myUrl)
        myparser?.delegate = MyXMLDelegate()
        myparser?.parse() // HERE the EXC bad access code 1
```

This is the content of the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addresses owner=”swilson”>
<person>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <phone location="mobile">(201) 345-6789</phone>
    <email>jdoe@foo.com</email>
    <address>
        <street>100 Main Street</street>
        <city>Somewhere</city>
        <state>New Jersey</state>
        <zip>07670</zip>
    </address>
</person>
```

What is the problem of the above code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: XML is missing closing tag for addresses

Comment: ... you also use curly quotes around "swilson", aside from this the actual code you use works (assuming your delegate functions correctly and that the file path is correct)

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoying, un-obvious bug I ran into. The problem is this line:

```
myparser?.delegate = MyXMLDelegate()
```

The delegate property is defined as un-owned. So essentially Swift is releasing your delegate right after this line, resulting in a bad access.

To fix keep a reference to your delegate

```
let delegate = MyXMLDelegate()
myparser?.delegate = delegate
```